# Expanding the Kali Root Partition

Tags: partition, kali-linux, gparted

I have a live distribution of Kali running on a usb with persistence. However, after installing updates and a few new software packages, the root drive is pretty much out of space.

How do I go about resizing this? I've tried booting GParted on a separate live USB and extending the drive, however GParted puts a little yellow triangle to the left of the `/dev/sdb1` partition and essentially locks it.

I have also tried resizing the disk during runtime using `resize2fs` but to no avail. I have been at this for hours now and I'm at breaking point so if anyone could help me out i'd very much appreciate it.

Below is a copy of my `fdisk -l` output:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 7.3 GiB, 7864320000 bytes, 15360000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0a9a1b1a

Device     Boot   Start      End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *         64  6324223 6324160    3G 17 Hidden HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdb2       6324224  6485375  161152 78.7M  1 FAT12
/dev/sdb3       6486016 15359999 8873984  4.2G 83 Linux

Disk /dev/loop0: 2.8 GiB, 2969686016 bytes, 5800168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the text mode to resize partitions you can try parted: 
https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-disk-storage-parted-resize-part.html

Comment: Is there any graphical tool? and would a CentOS tool work on Kali? Or will i have to download and boot a CentOS distro?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `cfdisk`? It's a command line based partition editor, and it's worked for me whenever I needed to do anything involving creating/resizing partitions.

Comment: How would one use this?

Comment: Go to bash, and type 'cfdisk' with superuser privileges (i.e. with 'sudo' or after an 'su' or 'sudo su'). You should see a menu pop up where you can select/alter/resize partition tables. If you've not heard of this command until now, then I feel obligated to point out that reading the man page would be helpful.